# how to click on an element that changes its position in real time on canvas

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a canvas element on the page and I want to click to some element if in a certain area an element of a certain value will appear
For Example (See screen)
In the selected area there is an element whose value changes (see green line) (All white zone is canvas element). I need to click on the button if the value of this element is equal, for example, 10[Example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4qNM.png)

how to implement it using Selenium Webdriver and Java

Comment: Your code trials and error (if any)?

Comment: I don't have code, because I don't know how to work with a canvas element. If I could get the element through id, xpath or css - I would not have problems

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can't see inside of a `CANVAS` HTML element. You will have to talk to your devs and put JS hooks in there to determine position of the arrows, etc. and then perform actions based on that. You can run those JS calls through Selenium JavaScriptExecutor. See [the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html).